# Show Push Notification for time which user has set

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented the Push Notification Successfully in the application, and I need to provide an option to user Where they can set the *time for not showing receiving notification*. all other time they can receive. I am storing the detail of their Do Not Disturb time in the database in the backend. I just want  to check when the notification is fired. the current device time of user. and if that falls under their DND time. Notification is not to be shown and event the sound is not to be shown. Even in the Notification Section.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the the timezone of the device along with the schedule. Depends on the time you need to fire the notification from your server.

i.e, once you fired the notification from your server you can't stop it from showing

Comment: Thank you. !! you have made my Day.. Cheers !! it worked I added the timezone field in that database and got the current time based on timezone and firing and not firing worked